# Тур по сайту на AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

Есть задача сделать на сайте тур, по такому принципу: выделяется элемент страницы (например кнопка), все вокруг него затемняется, рядом появляется поясняющий текст к этому элементу и кнопка "Продолжить", с переходом на следующую подсказку.

Используем AngularJS, с которым существующие библиотеки типа IntroJS или Angular-Tour либо не работают, либо работают только со старыми версиями.

Хочется понять принцип, как выделяется объект и рисуется к нему подсказка например в Ангуляре, чтобы реализовать это самостоятельно.

Либо, если есть реально работающая с 1.5.9 библиотека для создания тура по сайту, дайте пожалуйста ссылку. Пока рабочего варианта не видел.